# Howto read updated shared preferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have two Activities: one (SettingsActivity), which saves preferences in onStop() like this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

editor.putString("login", etLogin.getText().toString());
editor.putString("password", etPassword.getText().toString());

editor.commit();
```

and second one (MainActitivy), which reads them in onResume() like

```
SharedPreferences prefs = activity.getSharedPreferences("myprefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.getString(...);
```

When I change settings and return back to main activity, old values are loaded! I have to open SettingsActivity again and go back again, to changes take place.

Is onStop() with saving routines running in separate thread next to onResume() so when reading, changes are not commited yet? How to achieve correct behavior?

Dirty solution idea: I'm thinking about a singleton, which holds my preferences and has save() and load(), but this is ugly solution and I want to know, how to do this properly.

Answer (score 0):

Did the SettingsActivity has stoped if no you have to call finish(); to call the onstop() method ([activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png)) after saving username and password.

If you just call your save method and go back to the main activity by hiting the back button the onStop() method is not fired. Because the SettingsActivity is still running and paused in background.

Comment: yes, onStop() has been called. but it is called after (or runs next to) onResume()

Comment: I have logger called in onStop() and output is printed, so onStop() is called I think.

Comment: do you call super.onStop() and super.onResume() at the end of your onStop() and onResume() methods? may this fixes your problem!?

Comment: yes, I'm calling them both, i tried to call them before save/load and after, still the same :-(

Comment: ok, I moved it to onPause() and also did that singleton I mentioned before :-)