# Howto read updated shared preferences between applications?

Tags: android

I met an issue very similar with the following, but it's different.

[Howto read updated shared preferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378975/howto-read-updated-shared-preferences)

I've two applications, A.apk has quite a few sharedPreferences need to be fetched from B.apk. I can totally read it from B without a problem. However, when the preferences of A are changed, and then return to B.apk (onResume). Now the preferences fetched from A are not updated. I've to force close the B.apk and restart it to read the updated preferences.

I've also tried to use finish() while leaving A, however, it's not working. Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried using `editor.Apply();` instead of `editor.Commit();` when updating your preferences?
(Where `editor` is your PreferenceManager)

Comment: Are you calling `getSharedPreferences(...)` in the `onResume()` method of B each time or are you holding the `SharedPreferences` in B and re-using it??

Comment: Hi, Squonk. Yes, I am calling it onResume of B each time.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a ContentProvider in B.apk, and read/updated preferences in A.apk.